# How to Convert animated curve keyframes to Mesh or Grease Pencil

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, conversion

I have made a 3 second Text Converted to curves keyframe animation  and now after 3 seconds I want convert the converted text curve to mesh or grease pencil preserving the curve keyframes
The moment I convert curves to mesh or grease pencil all the 3 seconds keyframes also vanishes, disappears

Is there a way out to do so ...
first curve animation and then after few seconds mesh animation and thereafter few seconds grease pencil animation and vice-versa but preserving all the before keyframe animations.

I have used bevel keyframe animation to start with and thereafter I want to convert entire text into mesh or grease pencil preserving bevel keyframe so that I animate text after 4 seconds.

[image]